# Rsync to multiple directories with one command?

Tags: backup, rsync

I want to rsync my working directory to two other directories. One destination would be for backup, another for testing it.
I tried this:

```
rsync -av --exclude='.git' source dest1,dest2
```

But then I get error - `'dest1,dest2'` directory was not found. So it looks like it sees this as one directory path. Of course I would run command twice with different destination directory, but that adds up, and I would like to always rsync without needing to use multiple commands.

Is it possible to do someting like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps use a `for` loop:

```
for dest in dest1 dest2; do 
    rsync -av --exclude='.git' source $dest
done
```

Comment: this method gives several outputs for rsync.

Comment: -1 because these are two commands ("rsync ... dest1" and "rsync ... dest2") and not one as requested in the question.

Comment: @daniel.neumann, actually there are 4 commands `for`, `do`, `rsync -av --exclude='.git' source $dest` and `done`

Answer (score 2):

The suggested for loop solution works, but if you're transferring a large amount of data, it will be very slow. This is because it serializes the jobs, which are bound by the speed of disk-write. A better but slightly more complex alternative is to use GNU Parallel:

http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

You can come up with a command to parallelize multiple rsync runs, which would be N times faster if you're writing to N disks at the same time.

A similar parallel solution for a network-bound problem is given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058544/speed-up-rsync-with-simultaneous-concurrent-file-transfers

Comment: Will parallel take care of saving excessive disk read?

I want to read from 1 device and copy the contents to 20 other. No need to read the same data 20 times, I wonder if there's a way to achieve that.

I know that dc3dd (a modified version of dd) can read and write to multiple destinations in parallel with single read, but that's not very convenient for copying directories. Would work great for disk images though.